# vue.js data not updated after clear

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue.js item in my page that tracks changes made to a form. It looks like this:

```
var changes_applied = [];

var changes_applied_block = new Vue({
    name: "ChangesApplied",
    el: '#changes-applied',
    data: {
        items: changes_applied
    },
    methods: {
        remove: function(index) {
            changes_applied.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

When a change is detected the change is pushed onto the `changes_applied` array, and it shows up in the "Changes Applied" div as expected. The deletes also work, which just calls the `remove` method on the vue object.

I also have a "clear" button that's not connected to the vue instance, and when it's clicked it sets the data source back to an empty array using `changes_applied = [];`

The problem is that after this is cleared using the button, the changes / additions to the changes array no longer show up in the vue element-- it's like the vue element is no longer attached to the `changes_applied` array.

Am I missing a binding or something here that needs to happen, or is there a "vue way" to clear the vue data without touching the actual source array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark_M already provided a good explanation, I'll add a demo, since I think its easier to understand how it works.

You can copy the value of the array to data, but then all operations must be done to the data directly:

```js
const changes_applied = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3}
];

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {items: changes_applied},
  methods: {
    add() {
      const id = this.items.length + 1
      this.items.push({id})
    },
    remove() {
      this.items.pop()
    },
    clear() {
      this.items = []
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="add">Add</button>
    <button type="button" @click="remove">Remove</button>
    <button type="button" @click="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
  <ul name="list">
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      Item {{ item.id }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be changing the `changes_applied` array; Vue isn't really reacting to changes on that array. It only *sort of* works when `this.items` is pointed to the same array reference. When you change that reference by reassigning `changes_applied` it breaks because you are then manipulating `changes_applied` but it is not longer the same array as `this.items`.

You should instead be manipulating `this.items` directly:

```
methods: {
    remove: function(index) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

To clear it you can set:

```
 this.items = []
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your items array is initialized with changes_applied but does not mantaing bindings, it's just the default value for items when the instance is created. So if you change the changes_applied this will not affect the items array on vue instance.

example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: myArr,
      newItem: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem () {
      this.items.push(this.newItem)
      this.newItem = ''
    },
    remove (index) {
      this.items.splice(index, 1)
    },
    clear () {
      this.items = []
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="newItem" /> 
  <button @click="addItem">Add</button> 
  <button @click="clear">Clear</button>
  <p v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="remove(index)">{{item}}</p>
</div>
<!-- from outside vue instance-->
<button onClick="clearFromOutside()">clear from outside</button>
<script>
var myArr = ['hola', 'mundo'];
  function clearFromOutside() {
    console.log(myArr)
    myArr = [];
    console.log(myArr)
  }
</script>
```